# Force the app to go always the same form when it goes to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

I'm working on an app with many forms and the user may be in any of these forms and decides to go the application to background.
How do I force the app to go always the same form when it goes to background?

The avoidance of doubt I try to explain better with example:
There are 45 Views in my app. The user can be on View 1, 2, 3, 4.... But when he puts the app to background, I want to immediately go to the View 9. 
Thank you.

Comment: Save state, restore state?

Comment: If it just goes to background, you don't have to do anything. If user closes app, the only way is to save state and load it on next start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using the notification.

In View 9 I wrote:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                               selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                                   name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                                 object:nil];
}
```

View 9 will wait a notification when the app will enter in background.

In the same View:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification {

     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"main" sender:self];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"main"]) {
         View9 *view9 = segue.destinationViewController;
         [view9 setDelegate:self];
         ...
    }
}
```

When the app goes to background (whatever View is), the iOS will send a notification and the View 9, that is observing, will trigger the event applicationDidEnterBackground where I manually will call the event prepareForSegue.

In Storyboard segue there is a identifier "main" that leads to the view 9.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the [**State Preservation and Restoration**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html) in your app.

> The state preservation system in `UIKit` provides a simple but flexible
>   infrastructure for preserving and restoring the state of your app’s
>   view controllers and views.
>
> The job of the infrastructure is to drive
>   the preservation and restoration processes at the appropriate times.
>   To do that, `UIKit` needs help from your app. Only you understand the
>   content of your app, and so only you can write the code needed to save
>   and restore that content.
>
> And when you update your app’s `UI`, only you
>   know how to map older preserved content to the newer objects in your
>   interface.

There are three places where you have to think about state preservation in your app:

- Your app delegate object, which manages the app’s top-level state
- Your app’s view controller objects, which manage the overall state for your app’s user interface
- Your app’s custom views, which might have some custom data that needs to be preserved

Look into:

- [iOS App Programming Guide - State Preservation and Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html)
- [UIViewControllerRestoration Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerRestoration_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIViewControllerRestoration)
- [An iOS 7 State Preservation and Restoration Tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_State_Preservation_and_Restoration_Tutorial)

Comment: Thanks reecon for your replay, but this solution is not good for me. Perhaps I have not explained well. When the app goes to background, I have to change view. When the app is closed, I no have a problem.